# Fast Phong shading

Tags: c#, graphics, 3d

So i'm trying to write a simple 3d-application (for study only).

I want to do shading using Phong. So i'm reading [this article](http://freespace.virgin.net/hugo.elias/graphics/x_polyp2.htm) and see

> Since this can be slow, there are various ways you can speed it up if you don't mind a little loss of freedom. If you assume that the light source is at the same place as the camera, then you can ignore the V and H vectors altogether. Instead take the X and Y components of the normal vector, multiply by 128 and add 127 (assuming that is that the magnitude of the normal vector is 1).

okay, i can do it, but now, what should I do with this `X` and `Y`? I have array of triangles, each has calculated normal. I'm calculating this `X` and `Y`, but what should i do with? This code works, but not properly, because in this case light source is in `0,0,0` when i assume that it's in camera point.

Invalid code is here:

```
    public override void Draw(Graphics graphics, VisualizableShape shape)
    {
        if (!shape.IsVisible)
            return;
        base.Draw(graphics, shape); // draw edge
        int x = (int) (shape.Normal.X*128 + 127);
        int y = (int) (shape.Normal.Y*128 + 127);
        int z = x + y;
        var color = Color.FromArgb(255, (Pen.Color.R*z)/511, ((Pen.Color.G*z)/511), (Pen.Color.B*z)/511);
        graphics.FillPolygon(new SolidBrush(color), shape.Points.CastToPointF());
    }
```

just dunno what should I do in this case...